# How to route network traffic through an interface on another host?

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall, route, interface

I have limited networking knowledge, so please bear with me :)

I have a host that runs a VM that has 2 interfaces (ens33 and crc). My host has an interface (eth0) that is on the same subnet as "ens33".

I need to connect to this URL that is available only through "crc" from the host's interface (eth0).

While I can do the name resolution directly through /etc/hosts. I am unsure how can I route the traffic from eth0 to crc.

Furthermore, the host has firewalld enabled. The VM has iptables enabled.

Eg.

```
[host]
eth0 IP = 192.168.0.101

/etc/hosts
192.168.131.11    abc.testing.com


[VM]
ens33 IP = 192.168.0.125
crc IP = 192.168.13.1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's the relevance of the entry from `/etc/hosts`? It doesn't seem to figure anywhere in the question

Comment: With my limited networking knowledge, I was thinking if I hardcode the resolution into /etc/hosts, then all I need is to figure out a way to route the traffic from eth0 to crc.